# How can I write these loops in C instead of using #define?

Tags: c

```
#define loop_x for (int x = 0; x < w; x++)
#define loop_y for (int y = 0; y < h; y++)
#define loop_xy loop_x loop_y

void game(int w, int h)
{
    unsigned univ[h][w];
    loop_xy univ[y][x] = rand() < RAND_MAX;
}
```

How can I rewrite this code without using #define ?

Comment: Run it through the preprocessor and look at the output.

Comment: You do know that the preprocessor simply 
*replaces* macro invocations with the body of the macro? Now try do to that replacement yourself.

Comment: Exactly what are you trying to do here?\

Comment: Also, since you're asking about C why do you have the C++ tag? Especially since C++ doesn't have [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array).

Comment: `loop_xy univ[y][x] = rand() < RAND_MAX;` --> `loop_x loop_y univ[y][x] = rand() < RAND_MAX;` --> `for (int x = 0; x < w; x++) for (int y = 0; y < h; y++) univ[y][x] = rand() < RAND_MAX;`

Comment: Sorry my bad for including C++. I'm totally new to programming and I'm a bit confused here. I tried replacing the loop_xy with the for loops from #define but they don't appear to be correctly placed. If someone could take 5 seconds to show me how I'm supposed to place them I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Why don't you edit the question to include what you did try? And also include the errors you get from it, then we can easily explain what mistakes you made and how to fix it.

Comment: Function `rand()` returns a value between 0 and RAND_MAX, so the expression `rand() < RAND_MAX` will be 1 most of the time, and 0 in one in RAND_MAX cases (very rare). Is this what you want?

Answer (score 2):

So you have:

```
#define loop_x for (int x = 0; x < w; x++)
#define loop_y for (int y = 0; y < h; y++)
#define loop_xy loop_x loop_y

void game(int w, int h)
{
    unsigned univ[h][w];
    loop_xy univ[y][x] = rand() < RAND_MAX;
}
```

Start by resolving *loop_xy* into *loop_x* *loop_y*:

```
    #define loop_x for (int x = 0; x < w; x++)
    #define loop_y for (int y = 0; y < h; y++)
    #define loop_xy loop_x loop_y

    void game(int w, int h)
    {
        unsigned univ[h][w];
        loop_x loop_y univ[y][x] = rand() < RAND_MAX;
    }
```

Then resolve *loop_x* and *loop_y*:

```
    #define loop_x for (int x = 0; x < w; x++)
    #define loop_y for (int y = 0; y < h; y++)
    #define loop_xy loop_x loop_y

    void game(int w, int h)
    {
        unsigned univ[h][w];
        for (int x = 0; x < w; x++) for (int y = 0; y < h; y++) univ[y][x] = rand() < RAND_MAX;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Macros are literally text replacement in C code. So you can very very easily do that.

Replace

```
loop_xy
```

with its contents

```
loop_x loop_y
```

And then replace those with their contents:

```
(int x = 0; x < w; x++) (int y = 0; y < h; y++)
```

voila. Thats what your compiler does if you compile this.

Answer (score 0):

Just expand the macros:

```
    void game(int w, int h)
    {
        unsigned univ[h][w];
        for(int x = 0; x < w; x++) {
            for(int y = 0; y < h; y++){ 
                univ[y][x] = rand() < RAND_MAX;
            }
        }
    }
```

you can also see the pre-processed output if you compile the .c file with -E option. It will create a file with .i extension, which will be a pre-processed output, where you can see how the macro expansion is being done.

Answer (score 0):

`#define` is just a search and replace preprocessor command, all you need to do is replace loop_xy with what it is defined as.

```
void game(int w, int h){
    unsigned univ[h][w];
    for (int x = 0; x < w; x++)
        for (int y = 0; y < h; y++)
            univ[y][x] = rand() < RAND_MAX;
}
```